# Открыть изображение на весь экран при нажатии на ImageView

Tags: android

В `ImageView` загружается картинка из папки с памяти устройства. Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на `ImageView` картинка если существует открывалась в окне на весь экран?

```
String completePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + dirName + File.separator + recipe.getImage();
File file = new File(completePath);

if (file.exists()) {
    Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    Glide.with(RecipeActivity.this)
            .load(imageUri)
            .into(recipeImage);

    recipeImage.setTag(completePath);
} else { 
    recipeImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image_bg); 
    recipeImage.setClickable(false);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант.

Сохраняете путь к файлу картинки в свойстве `Tag` `ImageView`. На сам `ImageView` вешаете обработчик `onClick`, в котором открываете новый `Activity` c `ImageView` для полноэкранного просмотра.

Разумеется, что перед открытием нужно проверить существование файла и передать в `Intent`, через которые открываете `Activity`, путь к файлу.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось.

Comment: Проблема возникла у меня. Если файл физически удален с папки, то картинка все равно отображается. Из первого активити передаю в активити для просмотра картинки путь к изображению и создаю файл передавая путь к картинке. Дело в том, что если даже картинки нет реально, то она отображается в ImageView. Почему?

Comment: Возможно Вы просто не очищаете `ImageView` или соответствующие данные в приложении. Но, без кода точно сказать не получится.

Comment: Код могу скинуть, Вам какой именно код нужен? Где я вывожу изображение в ImageView?

Comment: Код лучше приложить к новому вопросу. Сайт работает по принципу: одна проблема = один вопрос.

Comment: Вроде получилось. Вопрос обновила. Создаю файл передавая ему путь к картинке. Если файл есть, то вывожу, иначе, если файла нет то картинка по умолчанию. Правильно же?